# How to run a .command file in its directory?

Tags: macos, terminal

My issue is that as I share my project on GitHub I wish to enclose a run.command file containing the terminal commands. The .R files in the same root folder as the .command file.

```
Rscript 01-xy.R
Rscript 02-yz.R
```

But how can I set that the codes are evaluated in the current folder. Looking st like cd (folder of this file).
Thanks in advance,
M

Comment: Does ["How do I get the directory where a Bash script is located from within the script itself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-do-i-get-the-directory-where-a-bash-script-is-located-from-within-the-script) answer your question? Also, see [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
cd $( dirname -- "$0"; )
```